# Making multiple asynchronous calls to fetch result from multiple services in the single click of a button in flex?

Tags: ajax, apache-flex, actionscript-3, blazeds, parsley

In one of our project we are using flex for front end, blazeds/java in the backend. Its an existing code where services are prewritten. I have to make calls to 3 services in the backend (basically 3 remote objects) and get their result and store the result in an object and show the data of this object in a view.
Now in front end we are using Flex and Parsley Framework. I was thinking of the following approaches.

1) Making commands for each service call and storing the result in a shared object (model) and then displaying this model in the  view. In this approach the problem is some services are needed in some other web pages, but they donot need the same model.
  How should i handle this scenario ? Should i make a asynchronous remote call and fetch the result and then again dispatch and event with the event object storing the result.

2) Making a service call , wait for the result then make another call and wait for the result and then make other call, not sure if this is the right way ?

What is the best solution to handle a scenario like this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are the three remote calls dependent upon one another?  Reading this, I am not sure why you don't just make the three calls with three event handlers... the classic async pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I guess I am still confused about what your problem is, so I will just try to answer it by telling the approach I would take if I had three unrelated calls to make to a backend.

I would fire them all off immediately after one another.  Since backend calls in Flex are always asynchronous, they will return immediately.  Each one of these calls will include a callback function for when the result is returned.  So, in pseudo(ish)code, it would be something like this:

```
makeRequest1(whenRequest1Finishes);
makeRequest2(whenRequest2Finishes);
makeRequest3(whenRequest3Finishes);
```

In this case `makeRequest*` is a method that knows what the server/mechanism is to make the call and will call back to a function you have defined some place called `whenRequest*Finishes`.

Assuming, now that there are three different parts to your UI being updated separately from each one of these requests, I would populate those areas of the UI as they come in.  I wouldn't simply populate them, though... I would give the user an indication that they have arrived.  This can be a subtle animation of the data "flying" in or a wait indicator that disappears when the data shows up.  Instead of three separate wait indicators, you might make one wait indicator that filles the entire UI that doesn't go away until all three are received.

Whatever the case, I would never make the calls in a serial way UNLESS the calls were dependent upon one another.  Use the built-in asynchronicity in Flex to your advantage and make all three calls in parallel.

Is this what you are looking for???

Comment: Sorry that i was not very clear.Thanks for the reply, my problem is not in calling the remote services.The problem is in accumulating the results and storing them in a model.What i am trying to do is make each service call in a separate command (action script class, similar to a delegate object), so that this call can be reused in multiple pages, i donot want to repeat the code for the calls in different pages. So basically makeRequest2(whenRequest2Finishes) will be in a command or class of its own and similarly others. The only thing is how do i populate the model if i do that.

Comment: I am able to do this now, basically i have created a single command and inject the object of other commands in it.Each command makes a call to a specific remote service and i fetch the result in the main command and then use this result in the view.That way i am reusing the service level code.This is similar to a delegate pattern.Is this approach good.I am encapsulating services because the service call might change frequently as its done by a separate team, and i don't want to end up coupling all the wep pages with the code for making the call to services.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a single object which holds the three results of the calls and make every response handler put their response in the object and verify that they are not the last call to have arrived.

Example:

class ManyResult
  var firstResult:*
  var secondResult:*
  var thirdResult:*

function get complete():Boolean { return firstResult && secondResult && thirdResult; }

In each handler you would have this generic logic:
  parse result
  put parsed result in ManyResult object

if ManyResult.complete:
  method_which_glues_all_three_results_together()

I would not recommend using this solution if this problem is frequent as it easily gets messy. I'd advise making yourself some generic code which does this for you in a clean, standard way.